# Add id to the default template of jquery popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I want to create a popover, but I want to give an id to it as well. I'm trying to achieve this by setting the template like this. But when I try to show the popover, I get the error below

```
$("#myElement").popover({
            trigger: "manual",
            placement: placement,
            html: true,
            template: `<div id="` + id + `" class="popover fade bs-popover-end" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate(788px, 615px);"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>`,
            customClass: customClass,
            content: content,
        })
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
    at Qe.getTipElement (popover.js:100)
    at Qe.show (tooltip.js:241)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (popover.js:155)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.jQueryInterface [as popover] (popover.js:147)
    at PopoverList.Show (main.js:74)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works. 
You did a variable id in template. 
 Where does the id come from?
I gave id the value 1 for example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myelement').popover({
    trigger: 'manuel',
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: "And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?",
    title: "Popover title",
    html: true,
    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header"></h3><div class="popover-body"></div></div>'
  })
  $('#myelement').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('aria-describedby'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="myelement" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it's working. And the id is set before. I didn't post that part

Comment: Oh, actually it didn't work. I mean I do not get error, but the popover doesn't have the id that I've set

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check if it fits you. There is already an id created automatically by the popover self. See example above by console.log